Restrict fucntions when using AA
I want to restrict some funcitons, which have role-base-modifer, when using AA with gas sponsor (I currently use Alchemy).
What I want to realize is that only our backend can exec those functions.
The flow I'm assuming is first, users do stuff from our frontend with their AA (Privy or so) and backend send transaction to bundler.
Since the signer (msg.sender) is the user's AA and not our backend, require(msg.sender == hasRole(role)) doesn't seem work.
Is there good way to do this?

You can check tx.origin instead of msg.sender. It should be the bundler of the transaction, so the account you're using in the backend.

I know tx.origin has possible vulnerability. Do I have to use it?
